# Boolean logic in a single regular expression - possible?

Tags: regex

Can we put into a single regular expression , boolean logic : line starts with 'a' or 'b' . 
Question is triggered by using FileHelpers utility which does have a text box "Record Condition Selector" for  "ExcludeIfMatchRegex" . Utility is written in C#. 
^a - works , just don't how write down ^a OR ^b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `|` (pipe) feature:

```
^a|^b
```

Or, in extended formatting:

```
^a   # starts with an A
|    # OR
^b   # starts with a B
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in FileHelpers.
    [ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.ExcludeIfMatchRegex, "^\" | ^t")]

Comment: Spaces are significant in regexen.  the regex "^\" | ^t" means: "match the start of string, a quote, followed by a space, OR match a space, then the start of string, then a 't'."  Matching a space and then the start of string will always fail - it's impossible! :) Remove the spaces and it should work fine.

Comment: I didn't intend but managed to put spaces. And I didn't vote answer down.  Yes, all works for my needs.     [ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.ExcludeIfMatchRegex, "^\"|^\t|^3 T")]

Comment: +1, but note that this won't match the whole line - just the first character.

Comment: Which is fine: he's not trying to match the whole line.  If you take a look at his example, it's a C# attribute that "ExcludesIfMatchRegex".  So if it starts with what he wants, he doesn't care about the rest.

Answer (score 5):

How about this: ^[ab]

Comment: My understanding it should  work for  single characters at the start, and it does. I needed substrings also which can be done using other answer.

Comment: Doesn't this have to be negated like so [^ab] as ^ outside a character class stands for the start of the line.

Answer (score 3):

Having a hard time understanding you, but...if you're looking for a match if the string starts with "a" or "b", and a fail otherwise, you could do this:

```
^(a|b)(.+)$
```

Then, when you get the match's groups, the first group will be either an "a" or "b" and the second group will be the rest of the string.

Comment: I am not interested in FileHelpers internals, but your variant worked for me. 
      [ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.ExcludeIfMatchRegex, "^(\"|\t|3 T)(.+)$")]

Answer (score 2):

> A special construct `(?ifthen|else)` allows you to create conditional regular expressions. If the *if* part evaluates to true, then the regex engine will attempt to match the then part. Otherwise, the *else* part is attempted instead. The syntax consists of a pair of round brackets. The opening bracket must be followed by a question mark, immediately followed by the if part, immediately followed by the then part. This part can be followed by a vertical bar and the else part. You may omit the else part, and the vertical bar with it.

Check out [conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) page on regex.info for more details.